# Permission denied to non-root user for USB device

Tags: usb, permissions, hardware, udev, arduino

I'm having a lot of difficulty getting the Arduino Tiny AVR Programmer, aka (PMG-11801) to work on my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. This is an Arduino device that programs ATTiny85 chips in the Arduino IDE.

I have read several forum posts from various places and tried a solution that looks like it worked for many others but it hasn't worked for me. Here's what I've done.

```
mmachenry$ lsusb
... other devices ...
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 1781:0c9f Multiple Vendors USBtiny
... other devices ...
```

I note the 1781:0c9f for the vendor and product ID for the next step.

From various web pages I found, it seems like I need an entry in /etc/udev/rules.d to allow permission to use this device to non-root users. I added it and it looks like this:

```
mmachenry$ cat /etc/udev/rules.d/99-USBtiny.rules 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1781", ATTR{idProduct}=="0c9f", GROUP="adm", MODE="0666"
```

Also note that I'm in the proper group.

```
mmachenry$ groups
mmachenry adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev docker lpadmin sambashare
```

In order to have this take effect, ran these immediately after creating that rules file.

```
sudo service udev restart
sudo udevadm control --reload-rules
```

As requested by Norbert's comment, I ran a sanity check on my user groups but there seems to be nothing wrong as there is no output.

```
mmachenry@mmachenry-laptop:~$ sudo update-passwd --sanity-check --verbose
```

But when I run avrdude, I get permission denied.

```
mmachenry$ hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/home/mmachenry/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5-linux64/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -vv -pattiny85 -cusbtiny

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 11:00:16
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/home/mmachenry/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5-linux64/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/mmachenry/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : usbtiny
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found USBtinyISP, bus:device: 001:013
avrdude: Warning: cannot open USB device: Permission denied
avrdude: Error: Could not find USBtiny device (0x1781/0xc9f)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

However, I get much different, positive output when running the command with sudo.

```
sudo hardware/tools/avr/bin/avrdude -C/home/mmachenry/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5-linux64/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf -vv -pattiny85 -cusbtiny

avrdude: Version 6.3, compiled on Jan 17 2017 at 11:00:16
         Copyright (c) 2000-2005 Brian Dean, http://www.bdmicro.com/
         Copyright (c) 2007-2014 Joerg Wunsch

         System wide configuration file is "/home/mmachenry/Downloads/arduino-1.8.5-linux64/arduino-1.8.5/hardware/tools/avr/etc/avrdude.conf"
         User configuration file is "/home/mmachenry/.avrduderc"
         User configuration file does not exist or is not a regular file, skipping

         Using Port                    : usb
         Using Programmer              : usbtiny
avrdude: usbdev_open(): Found USBtinyISP, bus:device: 001:013
         AVR Part                      : ATtiny85
         Chip Erase delay              : 400000 us
         PAGEL                         : P00
         BS2                           : P00
         RESET disposition             : possible i/o
         RETRY pulse                   : SCK
         serial program mode           : yes
         parallel program mode         : yes
         Timeout                       : 200
         StabDelay                     : 100
         CmdexeDelay                   : 25
         SyncLoops                     : 32
         ByteDelay                     : 0
         PollIndex                     : 3
         PollValue                     : 0x53
         Memory Detail                 :

                                  Block Poll               Page                       Polled
           Memory Type Mode Delay Size  Indx Paged  Size   Size #Pages MinW  MaxW   ReadBack
           ----------- ---- ----- ----- ---- ------ ------ ---- ------ ----- ----- ---------
           eeprom        65    12     4    0 no        512    4      0  4000  4500 0xff 0xff
           flash         65     6    32    0 yes      8192   64    128 30000 30000 0xff 0xff
           signature      0     0     0    0 no          3    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00
           lock           0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           lfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           hfuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           efuse          0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0  9000  9000 0x00 0x00
           calibration    0     0     0    0 no          1    0      0     0     0 0x00 0x00

         Programmer Type : USBtiny
         Description     : USBtiny simple USB programmer, http://www.ladyada.net/make/usbtinyisp/
avrdude: programmer operation not supported

avrdude: Using SCK period of 10 usec
CMD: [ac 53 00 00] [ac 52 53 00]
avrdude: AVR device initialized and ready to accept instructions

Reading |                                                    | 0% 0.00sCMD: [30 00 00 00] [00 30 00 1e]
CMD: [30 00 01 00] [00 30 00 93]
Reading | #################                                  | 33% 0.00sCMD: [30 00 02 00] [00 30 00 0b]
Reading | ################################################## | 100% 0.00s

avrdude: Device signature = 0x1e930b (probably t85)
CMD: [50 00 00 00] [00 50 00 e2]
CMD: [50 00 00 00] [00 50 00 e2]
CMD: [50 00 00 00] [00 50 00 e2]
CMD: [58 08 00 00] [00 58 08 df]
CMD: [58 08 00 00] [00 58 08 df]
CMD: [58 08 00 00] [00 58 08 df]
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DF
CMD: [50 08 00 00] [00 50 08 ff]
CMD: [50 08 00 00] [00 50 08 ff]
CMD: [50 08 00 00] [00 50 08 ff]
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FF

CMD: [50 00 00 00] [00 50 00 e2]
CMD: [50 00 00 00] [00 50 00 e2]
CMD: [50 00 00 00] [00 50 00 e2]
CMD: [58 08 00 00] [00 58 08 df]
CMD: [58 08 00 00] [00 58 08 df]
CMD: [58 08 00 00] [00 58 08 df]
avrdude: safemode: hfuse reads as DF
CMD: [50 08 00 00] [00 50 08 ff]
CMD: [50 08 00 00] [00 50 08 ff]
CMD: [50 08 00 00] [00 50 08 ff]
avrdude: safemode: efuse reads as FF
avrdude: safemode: Fuses OK (E:FF, H:DF, L:E2)

avrdude done.  Thank you.
```

Running this inside the Arduino IDE has the same effect. As a normal user, I get permission denied. When I run the IDE as root, it works fully and uploads my program to the Arduino. Note that this device is recognized as a USB device, since it's the usbtinyISP, and not as a serial device like some Arduinos.

Why is the permission for a regular user to access this device still denied?

Thank you.

Comment: Looks very strange. You should run sanity check (see details in [*/usr/share/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.html*](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/doc/base-passwd/users-and-groups.html#INTRODUCTION)) of your passwd and groups files. Please run `sudo update-passwd --sanity-check --verbose` and add output (if any) to the question.

Comment: N0rbert, I did that. It doesn't seem to have any output which I think means my user-groups are in a sane situation. A good try though.

Comment: @mmachenry , probably udev rule actions are not applied for some reason. Would you check `ls -la /dev/` if it had got correct group and permissions and  add that line related USB serial to the question. Also for complete info `udevadmi info -a /dev/..`

Answer (score 5):

1. Make sure your udev rule is correct:

   ```
   SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{product}=="USBtiny", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0c9f", ATTRS{idVendor}=="1781", MODE="0660", GROUP="dialout"
   ```
2. Make sure to refresh udev:

   ```
   sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger
   ```
3. **Make sure to unplug and replug the USB device!**

The last one is what took me some time to figure out!

Comment: Note that an alternative to having to add your user to the `dialout` group in this case is to use `MODE="0666"` instead of `MODE="0660"`. This gives read-write (rw) privileges to ALL users instead of just to the owner (user) and those who are in the `dialout` (as set in this case) group. If you use `MODE="0666"` you can also delete the `GROUP="dialout"` part entirely, as it no longer matters.

Comment: Also, why are you doing `ATTR{idProduct}` instead of `ATTRS{idProduct}`? Is that a mistake? I see you use the `S` on this one: `ATTRS{idVendor}`. I think they should both be `ATTRS`.

Comment: Update on my first comment here: I may be wrong. Using `MODE="0666"` but not setting the `GROUP` did NOT end up working for me on Ubuntu 18.04. I then followed this tutorial (https://andreasrohner.at/posts/Electronics/How-to-fix-device-permissions-for-the-USBasp-programmer/) and set `GROUP="dialout"`, but did NOT specify any `MODE`, and since I am a member of group `dialout`, it works now!

Comment: Lastly, I think you need to use `sudo udevadm trigger` not `udevadm trigger`, but I'm not 100% sure. I just know that I used `sudo` and it seemed to make it work, and it takes ~2 sec to run with sudo and about 0.2 sec to run without it, so clearly different things are happening with vs without `sudo`.

Comment: @Jacob Minshall indicates in his comment under this answer that he required `sudo` too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/39370/how-to-reload-udev-rules-without-reboot/39371#39371.

Comment: @GabrielStaples Both work but it could be more consistent https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/424727/difference-between-attrs-and-attr-in-udev-rules